# Importing information on bridges into postgis-table using OSM2PGROUTING

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting, postgis-2.2

In OpenStreetMap (OSM) road data there is information about whether or not a road feature is a bridge or not (boolean). However, when importing into a postgreSQL data base for routing (pgrouting), using osm2pgrouting, I cannot find information whether a feature is a bridge or not. Is it possible to tell osm2pgrouting, or osm2po, to include this information somehow? Maybe in the mapconfig.xml?

I understand that OSM2PGROUTING uses the bridge-information for excluding nodes at a bridge-road intersection, but I need that information in later analysis.

Here is the column-heads for OSM road data:
[image: OSM_columns]

Versions:

- Windows 10
- Postgis 2.2.1
- postgreSQL 9.5
- pgrouting: 2.1.0
- OSM2PGROUTING 2.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking for pgRouting it keeps the original OSM ID as attribute, so you can load the OSM data with osm2psql for example into your database and afterwards link the tables using the OSM ID.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This will work. However, I'm now struggling with the osm2pgsql .style-file. Ideally, I would like to narrow down the imported lines_table to just include the osm_id and bridge columns. Is this possible? How would this be specified in the .style-file for osm2pgsql?